# Cant login with asp.net core Identity

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

So I am working on a project. Everything seems fine. I dont have any error or anything like that. 
But when I am trying to login into my website that I created with Identity, nothing happens. All the tables are in my database as it should be.

In the output in visual studio it says:

> info: GetThingsDoneMVC.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account.RegisterModel[0]
>         User created a new account with password.
>
> info: GetThingsDoneMVC.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account.LoginModel[0]
>         User logged in.

So it works. But when I try to login nothing happens. I get redirected to the home page and I still don't see that I am logged in. It still says up in the corner "Register" and "Login".

Have anyone else had this problem before? Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: This is usually because you've missed `UseAuthentication` or have put it too far down in `Startup.Configure`.

Comment: Hello, my App.useAuthentication is placed right above the App.UseAuthorization. Where should it be placed?

Comment: That sounds like the correct place. You might need to include your `LoginModel` class. Another thing to check is the browser's dev-tools, to see if theres a cookie for `Identity.Application`.

Comment: Same happens me when I switch from IIS Express to full IIS.

Comment: Please check after login whether cookie is getting created in browser dev tools. Also check if any kind of authorization attribute sending user back to login page?

Comment: as @KirkLarkin said, i had missed the UseAuthentication on progra.cs on aspnetcore 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also had it in the past and the problem was that I did not add `@inject SignInManager<Identity> SignInManager` and `@inject UserManager<Identity> UserManager` to the `_LoginPartial.cshtml` file. Also make sure that in the `_ViewImports.cshtml` file you have added `@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity` and `@using Myproject.Models` if you have a seperate models project.

Answer (score 1):

I fix the issue by going to the startup.cs and
changing

services.AddDefaultIdentity(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)

to

services.AddDefaultIdentity(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false)